# Separate clauses of an if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, clause

Is there any way to have multiple clauses in an `if()` statement?

For instance:

```
if( ($username=='textUser' && $role=='admin') || ($admin=='yes'))
{
    // If the username AND role are set to admin OR if the admin is set to 'yes'
}
else
{
    // Neither clauses of the if statement are true
}
```

Perhaps this is actually the correct code, i have no tried it - but if not, could anyone tell me how? :)

Comment: @tarnfeld - in future, it might be worth trying out your code before asking it it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually the correct code. Instead of `||`, you can also use `or` (although they differ slightly in [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), not relevant in the case at hand but worth noting, cheers @Timothy.)

I tend to put every condition `$a == b` into brackets: `($a == b)` to avoid funny situations in complex `if` statements.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend arbitrarily choosing `||` or `or` as each means something slightly different. They both mean "or", but the precedence of the operation is different.